# Access parallel member function of class

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two classes `c` and `f`. One member of `c` is an array of `f` instances.

```
class f {
    public:
        f() {};
        int testMethod() {
            // return instanceOfC.myInt; // That's what I want to do but of course I doesn't work by now because f doesn't know instanceOfC 
            
            // 1. extern c instanceOfC; // I don't want to use this because with this I need to know the name of the instance (= instanceOfC)
            // 2. Declaring myInt as static isn't possible because this variable changes with every instance of c
            // 3. I'd prefer to solve this without giving a reference/pointer to instanceOfC as parameter to the function
            return 0;
        }
};

class c {
    public:
        c(){};
        int myInt = 15;
    private:
        f allMyFs[3];
};

int main() {
    c instanceOfC;
    f instanceOfF;
    
    instanceOfF.testMethod();
}
```

Any ideas how to solve that without `extern`, without declaring `myInt` as `static` or passing a reference/pointer of `instanceOfC` to `testMethod()`?

Comment: store in `f` instances a back-reference or -pointer specifying which `c` it's owned by, and set/update that whenever it's added/moved in a `c` container. then you don't need to pass that to the member function, just read said member variable therein. not saying any of these are necessarily good designs, though!

Comment: You cannot do that without passing reference/pointer either in `f` constructor or in `f::testMethod`. The relation only exists from `c` to `f`, not the other way round. And in your very own code, with `instanceOfF` being unrelated to any `c`, which `c.myInt` should it return?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I know, but since I'm a absolutely newbie to C++ I had the hope there's a possibility for that...

Comment: @underscore_d How could I determine the owner of an `f` instance (= `c`)?

Comment: @alve89 You're the one who adds `f`s to a `c`, are you not? So, while adding each `f`, set its reference-/pointer-to-`c`, to be the `c` to which you are adding it.

Comment: *facepalm* This was so obvious, I'm ashamed of my own question...